# Why do I get this error when trying to use the int function

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm trying to create an if loop but when I try to use the int command, it says that the closing parenthesis after the 4 is an error. Why do I keep getting this error?

```
while (loop_count < legs):
  spider.goto(0,20)
  if loop_count < int(4)
    spider.setheading(angle*loop_count-45)
    spider.forward(leg_length)
  else
    spider.setheading(angle*loop_count+45)
    spider.forward(leg_length)
  loop_count = loop_count + 1
```

Comment: You're missing a `:` at the end of the if-statement

Comment: and of the else-statement

Comment: @rdas That was actually the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `:` after `if` and `else` respectively.

Try this:

```
while (loop_count < legs):
  spider.goto(0,20)
  if loop_count < int(4):
    spider.setheading(angle*loop_count-45)
    spider.forward(leg_length)
  else:
    spider.setheading(angle*loop_count+45)
    spider.forward(leg_length)
  loop_count = loop_count + 1
```